# Guardar datas de un formulario en distintas tablas

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Disculpen, he intentado hacer un código pero hice un desastre, por eso quiero hacer borrón y cuenta nueva.

Les pregunto, si tuvieran un formulario en **python** con los siguientes datos a guardar (nombre, dni, fecha, tel, email, direccion, barrio, localidad, código postal) y la correspondiente base en sqlite3, pero en vez de guardar todo en una sola tabla lo harían en 3:

- Persona (nombre, dni, fecha, tel, email)
- Barrio (dirección, barrio).
- Localidad (localidad, código postal)

Cómo automatizan eso para que al apretar el botón de guardar cada dato vaya su correspondiente tabla, sin usar `sqlalquimy` ni nada de eso, eso lo veré mas adelante como funciona ahora quiero hacerlo sin ese tipo de herramientas.

Gracias ... saludos